Getting "Cannot parse the request" when trying to create new Azure Cloud Service (New-AzCloudService)
I am using Powershell and trying to create a new Azure Cloud Services Extended Support (CSES) using the command New-AzCloudService but I keep getting "New-AzCloudService : Cannot parse the response.".

After much research, I found out that if can add a "-Debug" parameter to New-AzCloudService which then outputs useful debug information. On my case, the response sent by the server only contained "Cannot parse the request" but a careful examination of the body being sent I could see that the PublicIP.Id of my FrontEndIpConfigurations was empty. After I fixed that the CSES was created with success.
Here is a useful link about debugging Azure Powershell: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/troubleshooting?view=azps-12.0.0
